# File Check sum are not same after copy in C

Tags: c

I write one program to copy one file to another but after copy its giving me different checksum rather than actual one.

I want to copy one file to another if file contains `EOF or null` character then still i need to copy whole file from one to another (for example : zip file,tar file like that)

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        FILE *p, *q;
        char file1[20], file2[20];
        const int BUF_SIZE = 1024;
        unsigned char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        printf("\nEnter the source file name to be copied:");
        gets(file1);
        p = fopen(file1, "r");
        if (p == NULL )
        {
            printf("cannot open %s", file1);
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("\nEnter the destination file name:");
        gets(file2);
        q = fopen(file2, "w");
        if (q == NULL )
        {
            printf("cannot open %s", file2);
            exit(0);
        }

        fseek(p, 0, SEEK_END);
        unsigned int left_to_copy = ftell(p);

        while (left_to_copy > BUF_SIZE)
        {
            fread(buf, BUF_SIZE, 1, p);
            fwrite(buf, BUF_SIZE, 1, q);
            left_to_copy -= BUF_SIZE;
        }

        fread(buf, left_to_copy, 1, p);
        fwrite(buf, left_to_copy, 1, q);
        printf("\nCOMPLETED");
        fflush(p);
        fflush(q);
        fclose(p);
        fclose(q);
        return 0;
    }
```

I used above code but destination file gives me Different checksum means file is not copy as like source.

Thanks

Comment: Try `BUFSIZE=1`. Your algorithm implies the file's size being a multiple of `BUFSIZE`. Ans this is only always true for `1`.

Comment: Ever always check the outcome of relevant system calls!

Comment: Never use fseek to get the file size

Comment: `ftell()` returns `long` so it might be a good idea so assign its result to a `long`, otherwise you might lose significant information for large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *binary mode*: use `"wb"` and `"rb"` as `fopen()` second parameter.

Comment: I tried this But this is also not working? Any issue with char* or unsigned char* ?

Comment: You shoul use binary, anyway. Another issue: fseek() back to the beginning of the file before read() it.

Comment: Yet another issue: instead of writing BUF_SIZE bytes, use return value of read().

Comment: @ern0: Or set `BUZSIZE` to `1` ... |-|

Comment: Just a last issue, I promise, there is no more left: left_to_copy should be compared to 0 (zero), so the fread/fwrite will be unnecessaty outside the loop.

Comment: The final `fflush`es are unnecessary. Not only at the end, but *nowhere* in the code.